# Sharing code between a Web Applicationa and an iPhone App

Tags: php, ios, iphone

I posted this question a few weeks ago, but perhaps it came off as vague and wasn't really well accepted.  So I'm going to try and be more specific, since I am still looking for an answer.

I have an idea for an iphone app that I wanted to start working on. I'm a Web Programmer by trade, and was considering writing the application initially as a website. (intended for Desktop / Laptop users).  Once I figured out all the ideas, I was then going to use that as a blueprint for the iphone app.

My question is: It would be great to have both versions running, and thus, sharing as much code as possible.  Is there a practice, methodology, or set of principals for dealing with this sort of scenario?  For Example:  www.facebook.com and the Facebook iPhone app.

I'm thinking that the endpoints which the iPhone accesses to retrieve data, should be the same code that the Web Application uses to retrieve data.  Or with different platforms running, is it common practice to maintain completely separate code bases?

To be clear, my iPhone App would be a native iPhone app.

thoughts?

Comment: write your entire application data layer as web services (restful or some such) and then have your mobile app request data from the web services and your website request data from your web services.  That way you're writing a single process layer and your 2 distinct display layers are simply that display code all processing is done server side.

Comment: there is difference between facebook.com and Facebook app.Device app is a native app where design and data processing is done separately,only data is received from a server in some format(xml);Which is entirely different from the FACEBOOK.COM. To achieve what u want ,you have to make ur application a web application.Content from your website can directly call its url into your app but the contents will not be optimised for your device.

Comment: @vishnuvarthan To be clear, the iPhone App I'd be creating would be a native iPhone app.  And the web application would be a separate entity.  But like Facebook.com, they would share the same data

Comment: In that case you cannot use the same code; your web application or your website cannot use code or share the code with the native application.But you can use the same server data in both native and web app.But processing them should be done separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a webservice for that,you can use json or xml to create webservice response format.

you can use that webservice with any platform. by parsing json or xml you can get your data and display it according to your platform specific design.